How to make a React screensaver with dynamic layout (different sized images that the user can choose from)?
I'm making a screensaver that's finally going to be displayed on some displays. It's going to show multiple images that have animation effects on them (they flip, so 2 images lay on top of each other with position absolute and "flip around" using spring animations).
I've made a hard-coded version that works fine with a grid layout:
grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);
grid-template-rows: repeat(20, 1fr);

And my mock data looks like this:
const data1 = [
  { frontImage: img1, backImage: img2, gridColumn: '1/6', gridRow: '1/5' },
  { frontImage: img3, backImage: img1, gridColumn: '1/6', gridRow: '5/10' },
  { frontImage: img4, backImage: img1, gridColumn: '6/11', gridRow: '3/10' },
  { frontImage: img3, backImage: img2, gridColumn: '1/11', gridRow: '11/16' },
  { frontImage: img2, backImage: img4, gridColumn: '1/5', gridRow: '16/21' },
  { frontImage: img1, backImage: img3, gridColumn: '5/11', gridRow: '16/21' },
];

This data is then mapped to the image component which positions the different images like this:
<animated.img
  className="imageCard"
  src={data.backImage}
  style={{
    gridRow: data.gridRow,
    gridColumn: data.gridColumn,
    position: 'absolute',
    transform,
  }}
></animated.img>
{/* Front */}
<animated.img
  className="imageCard"
  src={data.frontImage}
  style={{
    gridRow: data.gridRow,
    gridColumn: data.gridColumn,
    position: 'absolute',
    opacity,
    transform,
    rotateX: '180deg',
  }}
></animated.img>

I'm trying to make logic which will calculate grid positions depending on the size the user chooses. Hopefully, in the near future, I will get provided an API with the data the user chooses. It probably will be data like the width and height of each image. For example, maybe something like this:
Upper: [
  { frontImage: img1, backImage: img2, width: '25%', height: '25%', flipTimer: 25 },
  { frontImage: img3, backImage: img1, width: '25%', height: '25%', flipTimer: 25 },
  { frontImage: img4, backImage: img1, width: '50%', height: '50%', flipTimer: 25 },
],
Lower: [
  { frontImage: img3, backImage: img2, width: '50%', height: '50%', flipTimer: 25 },
  { frontImage: img2, backImage: img4, width: '25%', height: '25%', flipTimer: 25 },
  { frontImage: img1, backImage: img3, width: '25%', height: '25%', flipTimer: 25 },
],

The display will be in 720x1280, and the user can then choose 1-4 images on the top 50% of the display and another 1-4 images on the bottom 50%.
I tried changing the grid rows/columns to 72x128 (1fr) to make more precise positioning, and I made some logic to divide the width and height into fractions. Something similar to this (I deleted the latest version, but it was similar):
const calculateGridPosition = (width: string, height: string, startColumn = 1, startRow = 1) => {
  const totalColumns = 72;
  const totalRows = 128;

  const widthFraction = parseInt(width) / 100;
  const heightFraction = parseInt(height) / 100;

  const columnSpan = Math.round(totalColumns * widthFraction);
  const rowSpan = Math.round(totalRows * heightFraction);

  return {
    gridColumn: `${startColumn} / span ${columnSpan}`,
    gridRow: `${startRow} / span ${rowSpan}`,
  };
};

Am I wrong in thinking I should do this in a dynamic way using CSS grid and some logic which chooses grid positions from the data height/width?
